# How to return data from PHP to a jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am posting some data using ajax. I want to manipulate that data and return to to the calling jQuery script.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "somescript.php",
  datatype: "html",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    //do something;
    }
});
```

Here is my somescript.php on the server:

```
  <?php
    //manipulate data
    $output = some_function(); //function outputs a comma-separated string
    return $output;
  ?>
```

Am I doing this correctly on the server side, and how do I access the return string when  the ajax call completes?

Comment: Using success: function(data) {alert(data);} alerts null.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I figured it out. Need to use echo in PHP instead of return.

```
<?php 
  $output = some_function();
  echo $output;
?>
```

And the jQ:

```
success: function(data) {
  doSomething(data);
}
```

Comment: if `$output` is an array, how will you return that array ?

Comment: If `$output` is an array, then use `json_encode` so: `echo json_encode($output)`

Comment: or do a `print_r($var)`, but getting it as an json object is better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7064478/13865853 if you want to return JSON I believe, just saw this and have not tried yet.  `echo` to return values is totally foreign to me coming form Python.

Answer (score 18):

It's an argument passed to your success function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "somescript.php",
  datatype: "html",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    }
});
```

The full signature is `success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)`, but you can use just he first argument if it's a simple string coming back.  As always, [see the docs for a full explanation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :)

Answer (score 5):

based on accepted answer

```
$output = some_function();
  echo $output;
```

if it results array then use json_encode it will result json array which is supportable by javascript

```
$output = some_function();
  echo json_encode($output);
```

If someone wants to stop execution after you echo some result use exit method of php. It will work like return keyword

```
$output = some_function();
  echo $output;
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the way you are doing it is perfectly legitimate. To access that data on the client side, edit your success function to accept a parameter: data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somescript.php",
    datatype: "html",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        doSomething(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought so, but alert(data) is popping up null. And I know $output in the PHP is not null. I'll try textStatus.