# PHP returning JSON to JQUERY AJAX CALL

Tags: php, json, jquery

I am still struggling to get my head around the ins and out of JQUERY, AJAX and PHP.

I can now call the PHP OK, process the form elements and send an email, but I am not handling the return to the AJAX.  I am always getting the `error:` selector activated and when I try to list the supposed JSON returned, I get info, that is obviously wrong.

PHP with supposed JSON return

```
<?php

touch('phpTouch.txt');
// process email
$email=1;
if ($email) {
    $value = array('return' => 1, 'msg1' => 'Message sent OK, we will be in touch ASAP');
} else {
    $value = array('return' => 0, 'msg1' => 'Message Failed, please try later');
}
$output = $json->encode($value);
echo $output;

?>
```

Javascript  and AJAX

```
function submitForm(evt) {
    $('#msgid').html('<h1>Submitting Form (External Routine)</h1>');
    if ($('#formEnquiry').valid() ) {
        $("#msgid").append("<h1>(Outside Ready) VALIDATED send to PHP</h1>");
            $.ajax({
            url: "ContactFormProcess3.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#formEnquiry').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("SUCCESS:");
                for(var key in data) {
                    $('#msgid').append(key);
                    $('#msgid').append('=' + data[key] + '<br />');
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR: ");
                for(var key in data) {
                    $('#msgid').append(key);
                    $('#msgid').append('=' + data[key] + '<br />');
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#msgid').append('<h1>(Outside Ready) NOT VALIDATED</h1>');
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
};
```

Listing of supposed JSON data

```
readyState=4
setRequestHeader=function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders=function (){return s===2?n:null}
getResponseHeader=function (a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bF.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}
overrideMimeType=function (a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}
etc etc
```

If anyone can advise as to what stupid mistake I have made, then I would be most grateful.

Comment: where is `$json` defined? You can just use `json_encode();`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @marc Version 1.6.2 on Google CDN

Comment: @Prisoner. I changed to your suggestion. I was obviously wrong. Copied code again, but still not working as I had hoped - same listing of spurious values

Comment: There should be an output status=... what is the value there?

Comment: @marc The status was 200.  Problem solved you were all right, when I changed my $json to json_encode I left in the leading $, so I was getting a PHP error  and even when I changed to the header() way the error was still there.  Apologies for being so stupid.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can return json in PHP this way:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried and I am getting the same result.  Why is `error: ` always being executed ?

Comment: Many thanks. I now understand why and you were right.  Now fixed and working

Comment: I added `exit` as there should be nothing after the JSON response, hope you don't mind.