# jquery ajax post success function variable

Tags: jquery

The code below is working fine (values are inserted into database in php page), except that I don't get back the variable in the alert.  Instead, the alert box starts spitting out an HTML page code.

```
var dataString = 'amID=' + amID  + '&aFname=' + aFname  + '&aLname=' + aLname  + '&aMi=' + aMi  + '&aDegree=' + aDegree  + '&aEml=' + aEml + '&aAdd=' + aAdd + '&aCity=' + aCity + '&aSte=' + aSte + '&aZip=' + aZip + '&aPhn=' + aPhn;

        $.ajax({
          async: false, 
          url: "create_invite_insert.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(data) {

            alert(data);


          }
        });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I doubt that your the "create_invite_insert.php" does not return any data

Comment: create_invite_insert.php is working fine, I just can't display the data in the alert box.

Comment: can you show us your php page?

Comment: Wound up doing this:
success: function() { myFunction(); }

I was able to grab the variable from within myFunction.

Comment: Your create_invite_insert.php return HTML. alert displays HTML.
What the question?

Answer (score 0):

Alert requires a string, but data probably is something different here. Try `console.log(data);`

Comment: console shows "<!doctype html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<!-- the "no-js" class is for Modernizr. -->

<head>

    

<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return Json from server read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call#answer-7064478). Then, in ajax success:

```
success: function(data) {
  // first
  alert(data.paramName);

  // second
  var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
  alert(strData);
}
```

In first option, you can see value of parameter with its name (paramName).
In second option, you can see all parameters inside returned Json data as string.

Comment: It returns a blank html page. What do you want to return with ajax?

Comment: I was hoping to see the dataString variable like so:
'amID=12&aFname=John', etc

Comment: Then you should return Json data from server.

Answer (score 0):

I think You're mismatching the "data" defined as your ajax request parameter list , with the "data" that is the parameter of the return callback function.

You'd better rename your callback parameter to: resp_data or anything else that won't be ambiguous.

```
var dataString = 'amID=' + amID  + '&aFname=' + aFname  + '&aLname=' + aLname  + '&aMi=' + aMi  + '&aDegree=' + aDegree  + '&aEml=' + aEml + '&aAdd=' + aAdd + '&aCity=' + aCity + '&aSte=' + aSte + '&aZip=' + aZip + '&aPhn=' + aPhn;

    $.ajax({
      async: false, 
      url: "create_invite_insert.php",
      data: dataString, //this will be your dataString value as "data" ajax parameter
      success: function(resp_data) { //this will be the response of your ajax request

        alert(resp_data);


      }
    });
```

Comment: alert shows "<!doctype html> <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]--> <!-- the "no-js" class is for Modernizr. --> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> </head> <body> </body> </html>"

Comment: that's what is returned by your php script. test directly your php url with the browser (using parameters in dataString) (out of ajax request), and you'll surely get the same response

Answer (score 0):

The `ajax()` success callback passes an Object as it's first parameter. This will be the data that you returned from the server. By default jQuery will guess the datatype. You can read more at the jQuery API site: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

To alert the content of the objet try `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: alert shows "<!doctype html> <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]--> <!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]--> <!-- the "no-js" class is for Modernizr. --> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> </head> <body> </body> </html>"

Comment: Looks like your server-side script is returning an HTMl page. you probably need a new script that will just return you the data you need instead.