# Phonegap POST doesn't work

Tags: jquery, cordova, response

I want to make a POST or GET to my Server to get the json back as alert but it doesn't work. The alert shows every try "[object Object]"

here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Loading data into a PhoneGap app</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://lars-dev.de/test.php',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log('In callback');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: This: { "name": "Lars" }

Comment: Then change `alert(data);` to `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` or just take a look at the console.

Comment: always: [object Object] :/

Comment: Can you post some of your php code? Because all I'm seeing when I try to run your stuff is a text response, not a json response. Also, in your dataType, it should just be "json".

Comment: Yes here is the code: <?php
echo '{
    "value": 57
}
';
?>

Comment: @Evolutio So that's your problem, you're simply returning a string, not a JSON object. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call) and then give your code another try.

Comment: This is in the test.php `<?php
echo json_encode(array("value"=>57));
?>` and the code is the same but I have this alert `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` and I don't get the 57