# Using AJAX to execute a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've created a custom template for wordpress and I'm trying to execute some php code (deleteUser.php) to delete a record from a db but I'm not sure how to run the code without using alert. At the moment I'm just getting an empty dialog box rather than my php code deleting a row from the db.

ajax part

```
<?php
    echo '<script>';
    echo    'function dltUser(siteID){';
    echo    "jQuery.ajax({";
    echo        "data: 'siteID=' + siteID,";
    echo        "url:"."'".get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/deleteUser.php"."',";
    echo        "method: 'POST', ";
    echo        "success: function(msg) {";
    echo            "alert(msg);";
    echo            "}";
    echo        "});";
    echo    '}';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

deleteUser.php - the code to delete a row

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php' );
global $wpdb;
$siteID = $_POST['siteID'];
echo '$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM my_site WHERE SiteID = %d",$siteID)';
```

?>

Comment: You need to return data from your PHP page, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call). Also note that using `echo` to output a large block of HTML/JS is very unwieldy. Why not just write plain HTML and then inject just the PHP variables where needed.

Comment: If you don't want to use `alert()` just delete that line :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan initially I echo'ed `$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM my_site WHERE SiteID = %d",$siteID);` but it didn't make a difference. Also I didn't use plain html because my javascript functions weren't being recognised for some reason so I did this as an alternative

Comment: @Condorcho would replacing the alert with just msg allow my php file to run. Sorry I'm new to ajax

Comment: Why do you wrap your query function in an `echo`? Delete `echo` from `echo '$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM my_site WHERE SiteID = %d",$siteID)';` and just execute `$wpdb->query(...);` After that, `return` a success message or a fail error to see if it worked, you can log it to the console using `console.write(msg);` instead of `alert()` if you don't want it displayed to the user.

Comment: @Condorcho thanks, I found an error in my sql. If you make an answer I'll sure to accept it

Comment: Done, posted it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap the `$wpdb->query(...)` inside an `echo`, that won't execute the query, it will just output the command as a string, and you want to `return` a value to the AJAX function after the code is executed, not `echo` it.

If you don't want to use `alert()` to prevent the message from displaying to the user, use `console.log()` instead, see [Console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Also, as Rory said, don't use an echo for every single line you write. Either use `.` to concatenate or write plain HTML and inject the PHP variables where needed.

---

Resuming, your code should look something like this:

Ajax:

```
<script>
    function dltUser(siteID) {
        $.ajax({
            data    : siteID,
            url     : <?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?> + '/deleteUser.php',
            method  : 'POST',
            success : function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

`deleteUser.php`

```
<?php

include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;

$siteID = $_POST['siteID'];

if ($wpdb->query("DELETE FROM my_site WHERE SiteID = %d", $siteID)) {
    return 'Success'; 
}

return 'Error';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the alert. An empty dialog box means alert is being called, but you have no message. However the PHP script ran returning an HTTP response with a 200 OK code. If you don't want the popup, remove the alert. If you want a message, echo something at the end of your script.

Oh, and ditch the closing ?> if there isn't any output after it.