# Return two Variables from function

Tags: javascript, php, get

I'm not sure how to put two variables from a function to JavaScript.
At the moment I return one variable to javascript and it works.
PHP function

```
...
$anzahl = 1;
return Response($anzahl);
```

And this is my javascript part, where i get the variable.

```
 $.get('/countPlayer?teamID=' + vVerein, function(finish){
                        var close = finish; 
...
```

And now I have another variable $home in the PHP function.
How to get both of the variables correctly in the javascript function?

Comment: create an array.

Comment: Your bits of code are very short. Too short to really understand what you're doing, or what the code is about. `return` should be part of a php function, and where are the closures of `(` and `{` in your javascript?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) from your function

The **Object** constructor creates an object wrapper.

```js
function getFullName(){
  return {
    fName:'Tom',
    lName:'Cat'
  }
}

var nameObj = getFullName();
//
console.log('Name :- '+nameObj.fName+' '+nameObj.lName);
```

You can return [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) from your function

The JavaScript **Array** object is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.

```js
function getFullName(){
  return ['Tom','Cat'];
}

var nameArr = getFullName();
//
console.log('Name :- '+nameArr[0]+' '+nameArr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send them using an object.
Example:

```
function myFunction() {
 let returnValueOne = 1;
 let returnValueTwo = 1;

 return {
  returnValueOne,
  returnValueTwo
 }
}
```

And access those properties like

```
const returnedValue = myFunction();
// returnedValue.returnValueOne
// returnedValue.returnValueTwo
```