# send variable from php to jquery - file upload script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I have a problem and I dont know how to solve it.

The point is I want to upload file to server via php (upload.php), generate new filename and pass new filename to my window (upload.html)

Here is my upload.html file that contains form for uploading files

```
<h1>Choose attachement</h1>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file">
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload">
</form>

//list of already attached files (here it is empty)
    <div id="attach"></div>

//information if file was uploaded
    <span id="n" style="display:none;">File was uploaded</span>

//javascript for handling upload
        <script src="upload.js"></script>
```

I use jquery to pass some information and handle upload, this is upload.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    $("#n").css('display', 'none');
    var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];  
    var form_data = new FormData();  
    //get actual filename
    var filename = $('#file').val();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', 
                dataType: 'text',  
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data){
                    $("#n").css('display', 'inline');
                    $('#attach').html("<span>" + filename + "</span>");
                }
     });
    });
});
```

And here in upload.php I upload file to server

```
//get actual filename
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name']; 

//generate original file name using specific function
$new_filename = generate_original_name(); 

//upload file using new filename
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/uploads/' . $new_filename);
```

And what I want to do is to pass $new_filename variable genereated with php, I want to pass it to my jquery update.js script to print it in my list of uploaded file.  I tried json and other ways but.. nothing. Does anyone know how to do it ?

After all Your replies I did..

I added to update.php those lines

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

and in update.js I added

```
var fo = $('#foo');
window.opener.document.getElementById('attach').HTML += fo;
```

then in div there is [object Object]

after use

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('attach').HTML += fo.toSource();
```

in div I can only see

```
({})
```

And I still dont know how to solve it :(

Comment: It seems that if the code works so far, you need to pass the  $new_filename back as the response. That is normally done using JSON

Comment: Return JSON from your PHP code that contains the new filename. Then you can display it in the HTML. Here's how you do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Also note that jQuery object do not have an `innerHTML` property. You need to use `html()` instead: `$('#attach').html("<li>" + filename + "</li>");`

Comment: and attach is not a list so `$('#attach').html("<span>" + data+ "</span>");`

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
echo $new_filename;
```

in the PHP script.

BTW, the HTML you're trying to create is invalid. `<li>` has to be inside `<ul>` or `<ol>`. But `$('#attach')` is a `<div>`.

Also, `innerHTML` is a DOM property, you can't use it with a jQuery object. It should be:

```
$("#attach").html("<li>"+data+"</li>");
```

Comment: Don't edit my answer. If you have suggestion for improvements, post a comment. Or post your own answer.

Comment: Your changes were too major. I was also in the process of saying the same thing.

Comment: See the bullet list of valid editing reasons. Your changes didn't fit any of those criteria.

Comment: @mplungian Feel free to edit to correct typos, formatting and similar minor mistakes. But adding something unrelated, like the fix to his Javascript, is outside the scope of minor edits.