# How do I return a php session variable with AJAX?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have been through a ton of other posts and cannot figure out how to do this.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'getSessionVariable.php',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
   },
   error:function(data){
      alert("error occured"); //===Show Error Message====
      alert(data); 
   }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?
   session_start();
   print_r(json_encode($_SESSION["Variable"]));
?>
```

This solution returns "error Occurred"

Second Ajax statement:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: 'getSessionVariable.php',
  contentType: 'json',
  success:function(data){ 
    alert("Sucess!");
    alert(data);
    },
  error:function(data){
    alert("error occured"); //===Show Error Message====
   // alert(data); 
}
});
```

The second AJAX solution runs successfully but returns the entire php page back, I am just looking for the session variable to be returned...

Comment: have you got any error?

Comment: use `echo` instead of `print_r`

Comment: Possible duplicate, verify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: @AlfredoA. That solution does not work, so I would not consider it a duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: @Quentin it was because of the short tag I was using. The link you gave is what led me to this conclusion, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because i was using a short tag. This oversight really hurt me this time, d'oh!

```
<?
```

and not

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are use the corrects tags `<?php ?>` opener

And for use of `<?= ?>` that replace `<?php echo "myString"; ?>`
you have to change your short_open_tag in php ini settings.

From PHP documentation you have:

> Version  7.0.0    The ASP tags `<%, %>, <%=,` and the script tag  are removed from PHP.

-

> 5.4.0 The tag `<?=` is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting.

Change in your code the `<?` for `<?php`
and to send json_encode you must use an `echo` istead of `print_r`

```
    <?php
       session_start();
       echo json_encode($_SESSION["Variable"]);
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you read this whole thread? I came to that conclusion already, and posted it, about 40 minutes before your post.

Comment: oh! i see, i have this windows opened by a long period of time!!

Comment: No worries! I appreciate your insight anyways :)