# Ajax function call to php function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a simple php function as below defined in one of my php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_test','test');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test','test');
function test(){
    echo "Hello";
}
```

I am calling above "test" function using below ajax function call

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('#prev_button_id').click(function(){
        jQuery.post(
            myAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action:"test",
                success: (response)=>{
                    console.log('Success:'+ response);
                },
                error:(response)=>{
               console.log('Failure:'+ response);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

I am expecting console output of "Hello" but I getting below undefined response

```
Success:undefined
Failure:undefined
```

Comment: I think you should try `return`ing "Hello" rather than `echo` it. I believe `echo` outputs the string onto the output media.

Comment: Tried `return "Hello"; ` no luck, same undefined response. @rkalra

Comment: echo is correct. You absolutely must have a wp_die or exit at the end of your handler. Not sure if it is causing your problem but the AJAX handler will not work correctly without it.

Comment: Added `exit();` no change in response

Comment: @Learner try `echo json_encode("Hello")` you could find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: Tried `json` too, no luck. It seems that my test function itself is not getting called.

Comment: echo with json is correct. The problem is action needs to inside a data object.

Comment: action is not an argument that ajax() understands. data is an  argument that ajax() understands.

Comment: I have limited knowledge in this field, can you please help with sample code.

Comment: Sorry, I help people write code but I don't give code that a user should be able to do himself. Please read the documentation - https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. Also, "echo with json is correct" should be "echo withOUT json is correct"

Comment: Actually, jQuery.post() has multiple forms - some with a named data member some without the named data member. The problem is your call doesn't match any of the forms. See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the below video, step by step and it worked.
Probably it had something to do with nonce
[AJAX in WordPress using admin-ajax.php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0Jw226QKAM)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('#prev_button_id').click(function(){

        var params =  {action:"test"}

        jQuery.post(myAjax.ajaxurl,params,function(data){
            if( data ){
                console.log ( data );
            }

        });

    });
});



add_action( 'wp_ajax_test','test' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_test','test' );
function test() {
    echo "Hello";
    die;
}
```

Try this code and don't forget to `die` after AJAX call also
make sure you are getting proper AJAX URL in `myAjax.ajaxurl`