# Show/Hide HTML Element Based on SQL Query Results through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm not sure if this is possible?

I have some HTML and would like to show/hide an element based on an Ajax call to a PHP file that runs an SQL query.

In other words, inside my PHP file I have a query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM main";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

If the number of rows in the table is > 5, I'd like to hide an HTML element (else show it). I know you can do this if your HTML elements are within a PHP file by doing something like...

```
$showDiv = true;
if ($rowcount >= 5) {
$showDiv = false;
}

<div <?php if ($showDiv === false) {echo "style=display: none;"} ?>>
```

But since I'm essentially going from html > ajax > php > sql I'm not sure if it's possible.

I was going to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://path-to-php/file.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#div").hide();
        }
    )};
)};
```

But then isn't the success variable just if the PHP file is executed or not?

Comment: You can send the `$rowcount` value to your ajax-call using `echo` or in json format and can simply fetch that value and compare i.e : `if(data >= 5){  $("#div").hide() }else { $("#div").show() }` .

Comment: So would you do something like this:
PHP: echo json_encode($rowCount)
AJAX:
success: function(rowCount) {
if... else...

Comment: Yes @DD1229 .Also , you can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064391/php-returning-json-to-jquery-ajax-call) this .