# returning json array in php to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

Im trying to return a Json array in php to jquery but keep receiving undifined. 
Im using a jquery Modal to load the login screen the user then logs in and if login is successful  i want them redirected if not to display that actions. The code im using is

```
show: function (dialog) {
    $('#loginForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var url = "../_Scripts/login.php";
        if (!username) {
            $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#loginReply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please enter your Username.').show().fadeOut(6000);
            return false;
        } else if (!password) {
            $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#loginReply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please enter your Password.').show().fadeOut(6000);
            return false;
        } else {
            $.post(url, $('#loginForm').serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data.status == true) {
                    // window.location = data.action;
                    alert(data.status);
                } else {
                    //$("#loginReply").html(data.action).show().fadeOut(10000);
                    //$("#username").val('');
                    //$("#password").val(''); 
                    //$("#loginProcessGif").hide();
                    alert(data.status);
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
```

The Login php page looks like so

```
if($login){
        include("mysql-.php");
        $password2 = $password;                 
            if($login_query > 0) {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $idx = $row["id"];   
                    $user = $row["username"];                   
                    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET lastlogin=now(), mdhash='$logincode', ip='$ip' WHERE id='$idx'") or die(mysql_error());
            }

            return json_encode(array('status' => true, 'action' => '../home/'));
        }
        else {
            return json_encode(array('status' => true, 'action' => 'Username/Password incorrect'));
            exit();
        }
else{
return json_encode(array('status' => true, 'action' => 'Username/Password incorrect'));
                exit();
}
```

Can anyone help to why im getting undefined Vars

Thanks

Comment: you can't just `return` a json encoded array in an if statement and expect it to go anywhere.... is all this code in some function you didn't show? Is there more?

Comment: No its not in a function. i originally used echo to return the data but i was struggling to refresh the page when the user logs in correctly and the page just loaded into the jquery window

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it. Found you can use

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'action' => 'Username/Password incorrect'));
```

to return a Json array :)