# how to show errors returned from php page on to jquery pop up

Tags: php, jquery, html

Steps I have to follow :

1. Click on link so that jquery pop up will appear
2. Fill some data e.g. sign up form
3. Form will be submitted against one php page
4. This php page will perform some validation
5. If there is any error it will collect all errors

Problem : I want to show the errors back on the same pop up (step 2), against the data entered so that user can correct data. How to achieve this?

Comment: So, return json with errors array. Do something like this one the server side: retrun json_encode(['status' => 'fails', 'errors' =. $errors]). And on the client check if status ok. If not show errors.

Comment: @Alex

What would be better approach?

1 : Keep jquery pop up html page & targeted php page different
2: Include html page inside php page itself

Comment: Depends of what you have now, actually, Pretty difficult to say without code you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you structured your code.I am assuming that you submit a form in jquery like

```
 function processForm()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'second.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: jQuery('#feedback-form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.error === 0) {
            jQuery('#success_message').show();
            jQuery('#feedback-form')[0].reset();
            reloadCaptcha();
            setTimeout("jQuery('#success_message').fadeOut()", 3000);
        } else {
            alert("There was an error with your submission.\n\n" + data.message);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

And on second.php,print your messages like

```
        $return = array('error' => 1, 'message' => $errmsg);
        die(json_encode($return));
```

Comment: hi, i have below code in my  php file & in jquery, pls tell me what is wrong here?

php:
`$b=array('test' => 'test1');
json_encode($b);`

jquery code:

`$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "login.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data)
                 {
                     alert (2);
                 },
                error : function(data) 
                 {
                  alert (1);
                  alert (data.test);
                        }`
i m getting alert of 1 but in second i am getting undefined instead of "test1"

Comment: resolved. dataType was mismatching. Now it is going into success block but got new problem. Value echoed from php page is not available in html file. I checked return value from php page and i know it is not null. searched & found reference on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call but it is not working.

Comment: pls help me here. i am stucked for 3 days.