# AJAX call is not working because it proceeds to go to the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of `PDF` links that is dynamically generated from the database.  I want to have a log to keep track of the users who download each one.

It seems to not work because after the link is clicked, it doesn't have time to do the `ajax` before redirecting.

Here is the javascript:

```
function insertlog(linkName)
{
    $.post( "insertlog.php", { linkName: linkName, user: "<?=$username?>" } );
}
```

Here is the link:

```
 <a href="http://www.test.com/media/pdf/test.pdf" onclick="insertlog('test.pdf')">test.pdf</a>
```

Comment: So redirect only after the AJAX call completes.

Comment: Can you give more context?  I would guess the problem is that you are not preventing default link navigation behavior.

Comment: How about ensuring that the redirect occurs only after the AJAX call occurs, or perhaps use a promise to wrap around so that your log and tracking functions also record AJAX call success and failure?

Comment: Yes, it has to redirect after the ajax call completes.  How do you do that?

Comment: If you `return false` from `insertLog`, it won't redirect to the URL as the `href` value. How/when you then take them there is upto you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script>                    
function logAndGo(target)
{
    $.post( "insertlog.php", { linkName: target, user: "<?=$username?>" } )
        .then(function(url) {
            window.location = url;
        });
}
</script>
```

Have the server return the proper URL as a response to the log POST. Then change the link to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="insertlog('test.pdf')">test.pdf</a>
```

An even better option is what @dave proposed: create a server-side page that handles redirecting, so you can just do something like:

```
<a href="getFile.php?id=1234">test.pdf</a>
```

By handling it on the server side, you have **much more control** over logging, which URL to redirect to, and so on.

Comment: Why use an `a` element then in the first place? If you don't want to use links, don't link.

Comment: What would it look like in the insertlog.php to return the URL?  I'm a little confused how the url variable gets sent to the .then(function(url)

Comment: @dave: Oops, I actually didn't read your answer before posting mine. Sorry; credited you.

Comment: @AaronBucky that is just `echo` on the PHP side. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution to what you want to do is instead of linking to the pdf directly link to the site your ajax script calls and pass the actually requested source as a parameter.

In your script you can then do the logging and redirect to the actual source (or have the script just return the actual source).

This also allows you to track users who block Javascript. And it doesn't require two requests. And doesn't require you to maintain unnecessary Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect in `$.post` `callback`.

```
<script>                    
function logAndGo(target)
{
    $.post( "insertlog.php", { linkName: target, user: "<?=$username?>" }, fucntion(){
            window.location = 'http://www.test.com/media/pdf/' + target;
          });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help everyone.  I took Nate's advice and here was the final solution:

```
function insertlog(linkName)
{
$.post( "insertlog.php", { linkName: linkName, user: "<?=$username?>" }, 
   function(linkName) {
        window.location = "http://www.test.com/media/pdf/"+linkName;
    });
}
```

and then added an echo in my insertlog.php at the end with the PDF file name.

My link looks like this:

```
 <a onclick="insertlog('1104.pdf')" href="#">1104.pdf</a>
```

Comment: FYI: This is mixing it up a little bit. If you are passing `1104.pdf` as a parameter to `insertLog()`, you don't need to return it from your PHP script (unless it needs to change for some reason). If you just want to wait until the request is complete, you don't have to return anything other than a "good" flag and then set `window.location` as you have it already, since `linkName` already exists in the function's scope.