# AJAX request response

Tags: ajax, request, response

I'm new with AJAX. I'm sending a request to start a PHP code on another page where couple of things need to happen. I have an algorithm on that page checking if all the things were done properly in right order. What I need is to return that boolean back to AJAX file, so that it would know that request was not only received, but finished in an intended way, so that I can add a *success:* function that would give a OK/NEY experience to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your folder:

```
AnyFolderName
             |--- index.php
             |--- script.php
```

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX Request Sample</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitform(){
            //get value of input whos id is username
            var username = $('input#username').val();
            //data to post to script.php
            var post = {username: username};
            $.ajax({
                url: "script.php", //<-- PHP Script where you want to post your data
                type: "POST",
                data: post,
                success: function(data){
                    //callback when request is finished.
                    //in our script.php, we just echoed the posted username, so it alerts whatever username you have input.
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
         <input id="username" name="username">
    </form>
    <button onclick="submitform();"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

script.php:

```
<?php
     //print out the posted data you have passed from the AJAX request
     echo $_POST['username'];
?>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did in the end in PHP file. That was the second problem why my request didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can return (true for success or false for unsuccess) variable in success function of AJAX. On the basis of that you can proceed next.

Dummy Example :

```
$.ajax({
            url: '',
            type:'POST',
            data: {'id':id},
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend:function(){

            },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('An error occurred!');
            },
            success:function(response){
                if(response){
                  console.log('yes'); 
                   }
                else{
                  console.log('no');
                }

            }
            complete: function() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for dataType suggestion. I lost a lot of time, not knowing about that parameter, and when I looked it up it seems it doesn't support booleans. That's when it all started coming together, when I went to pass yes/no strings.

Comment: pass true/false it means in php coding 1/null

Answer (score 0):

Oh it was my mistake. Went through dozens of pages, but finally found the answer on another thread (so mine is kind of a duplicate) :

[How to return data from PHP to a jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Have to use echo(); instead of return(); in PHP file!
And, of course, the corresponding dataType, which in this case "text".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../some/file/file.php',
    async: true, //this is important!!!
    success: function(response)
    {
        if(response)
        {
            //use local environment storage to save data
            localStorage.setItem('data',response);
        }
    }
});

//To request data
some_variable = localStorage.getItem('data').trim(); //trim is important!!!
```