# How to display product details without page being refreshed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing a website using php & MySQL, i have two functions
1. Grab data from database, 
2. display HTML view codes with a link to view individual product details using $_GET variable. 
Everything works perfectly. But i want the product details to load without the page being refreshed. I understand Ajax is capable in handling the task but i am not knowledgeable in Ajax. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Below are my codes example:

```
//Main product view
function product_view($product) {   
    $output = "";
    $output = $output . '<li class="col-sx-12 col-sm-3">';
    $output = $output . '<div class="product-container">';  
    $output = $output . '<a href="'. BASE_URL .'item/?id='. $productID .'&name='. str_replace(' ', '-', $product["name"]) .'"> product name</a>';
    $output = $output . '----';
    $output = $output . '----';
    $output = $output . '----';
    $output = $output . '</div>';
    $output = $output . '</li>';        
    return $output;
}

//Main product display
function get_products() {
    require(ROOT_PATH ."inc/db_connect.php"); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status='Active'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);                       
    return $query;  
}

//View page
$products = get_products();
if (!empty($products)) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo product_view($product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you will absolutely need ajax. Do some research, it's quite easy actually. Go for json solutions, they are lighter than returning full HTML code.

Comment: Too broad.  Take a look at some examples and tutorials on using AJAX.  Since you tagged the question with jQuery, you will find *many* simple examples using that library.  Make an attempt.  We'll be happy to help if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: You can do something with jQuery Ajax, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. Any example code please?

Answer (score 0):

To use AJAX as suggested in some comments of your question, you can use this sample code in your client side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'products.php',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data){
        for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            $('body').append('<li class="col-sx-12 col-sm-3"><div class="product-container>...'+data[i].attribute+'</div></li>');
            //append all information that you need
        }
    })

});
```

at your backend you need to return the JSON so:

```
$products = get_products();

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
echo json_encode($products);
```