# Using data from AJAX Reply to a PHP Script (JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Wording might be a bit off. I'm trying to use the Battle.NET API to retrieve some information regarding characters. I have a 'server' field, and a 'char name' field.

I've reviewed a few of the similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call), and maybe it's just my PHP new-ness but I'm getting confused on how to properly do it. I'm still not sure at all how to troubleshoot PHP errors.

What I did was design the HTML + PHP embedded into one 'php' file. **It Worked**. I then separated them into index.html + test.php **it worked** 
The main issue with that was a few things - I wasn't rendering the response, I JUST had it 'echo' the response. Which appears to have been in JSON

```
 {"lastModified":1477156067000,"name":"Thischaracter","realm":"Thisrealm","battlegroup":"Thisbattlegroup","class":1,"race":6,"gender":0,"level":110,"achievementPoints":20805,"thumbnail":"thrall/50/129432626-avatar.jpg","calcClass":"Z","faction":1,"totalHonorableKills":8657}
```

So the flow needs to be HTML Form - Submit -> AJAX -> PHP form (This is far as my "experience" goes, because I've never done anything with the response) -> MAYBE a getJSON from the PHP data? -> HTML output. I mention AJAX because I don't want the page to update. Just a 'div' or LI to be updated.

**index.html** -- I modified this form a bit before posting here to remove extra non-sense.

```
<form action="testingApiForBnet.php" method="post" id="myForm">
      <p class="inp-wrap search-wrap">
        <label for="search-field" class="search-label grid-25">Find</label>
        <input type="search" name="search-term" id="charSearch" class="grid-75"/></p>
      <p class="inp-wrap cat-wrap">
        <label for="categories" class="grid-20">on</label>
        <select name="search categories" id="servers" class="grid-80">
        </select>
      </p>
      <submit name="SubmitButton">
    </form>
```

**testAPI.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton']))
 {
 $charName = $_POST['charName'];
  ##$_POST['charName'];
$server = $_POST['servers'];
  ##$_POST['server'];
$bnetAPI = "https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/";
$apiKey = "apiKeyWouldGoHere";
// Example https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/$Server/$CharName?locale=en_US&apikey=$apiKey//
$request = $bnetAPI . urlencode($server) .'/'.$charName .'?locale=en_US&apikey=' . $apiKey ;
$response  = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
}
 ?>
```

The 'json_decode' and 'file_get_contents' I got from another thread, because I was getting non object responses. With those $jsonobj is putting out the object I linked above.

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $.post('testAPI.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
      alert(data);
     console.log(data)
    return false;
    })
});
});
```

Up until the "function (data)" this script is actually taken from another form I have that works successfully. Currently nothing is happening when I hit submit - No redirect, no response, no console.log - I feel like it's because I'm POSTing, and it needs to GET but then I'd still get 'something' from data?

Would appreciate any input. Also still unable to troubleshoot PHP, unless I run the PHP script directly. I feel this much just be functionality within the language.

Thanks!

**UPDATE Placeholder.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
 $charName = $_POST['charName'];
  ##$_POST['charName'];
$server = $_POST['servers'];
  ##$_POST['server'];
$bnetAPI = "https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/";
$apiKey = "key";
// Example https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/Thrall/Teodoro?locale=en_US&apikey=$apiKey//
$request = $bnetAPI . $server .'/'.$charName .'?locale=en_US&apikey=' . $apiKey ;
$response  = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo $response;
  exit();
}
?>
```

**UPDATE index.html (just JS portion)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('test2.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
     console.log(typeof(data));
      if (typeof data === 'string')
        data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (typeof data !== 'object') {
        console.log("failed to parse data");
        return;
      }
    data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(data);
    });
   /*

   */
   console.log('Data is not returning.');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery code refers to a form with `myForm` ID, but you haven't assigned the ID to the form. So you should add the `id` attribute as follows

```
<form id="myForm">
```

Next, you have to fix the URL you post to. It should be `testAPI.php`, but not `text.php`:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('testAPI.php', function (data) {
    // ...
  });
})
```

Since you are binding the `onsubmit`, and handling the post request yourself, you probably don't need the `action` and `method` attributes in your form. Since the `testAPI.php` returns JSON content, you need to decode it in the request handler. Also, with the `$.post()` call you don't send any data to the server. It is just an empty POST request. You have to pass the serialized form as the second argument:

**test.js**

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
  // note, `this` variable refers to the form node.
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('testAPI.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
    if (typeof data === 'string')
      data  = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
  return false;
})
```

The code parses `data`, if it is a string. The jQuery handler may pass `data` as Object in case if the response returned `Content-Type: application/json` (in fact, is the right MIME type for JSON data). So you I'd recommend fixing the MIME type in `testAPI.php`, and, yes, you should print the response instead of decoding (unless you need to modify it):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $response; // supposed to be a JSON string
exit();
```

If, however, you need a modified response, then decode it, modify, and encode, again:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$response['something'] = 'somevalue';
// unset($response['redundant_field']);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response); // supposed to be a JSON string
exit();
```

### Example

**test.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $search_term = $_POST['search-term'];
  $category = $_POST['category'];

  $fake_response = [
    'term' => $search_term,
    'cat' => $category,
    'somethingelse' => date('r'),
  ];

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($fake_response);
  exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="search" name="search-term" id="charSearch"/>
    <select name="category" id="servers">
      <option value="optA" selected>optA<option>
      <option value="optB">optB</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
  </form>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('test.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
      if (typeof data === 'string')
        data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (typeof data !== 'object') {
        console.log("failed to parse data");
        return;
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Sample output (in the browser's console)**

```
Object { term: "rr", cat: "optA", somethingelse: "Sun, 23 Oct 2016 05:10:50 +0000" }
```

Comment: Sorry the PHP one was just a mistake in naming when I pasted in SO (It's correct).
However, I did have the wrong form ID in this version.. But It still isn't redirecting. Updating code.

Comment: @DNorthrup, updated the answer. Still, it shouldn't redirect. The jQuery `$.post` performs an AJAX request. And AJAX requests are designed to perform HTTP requests without the need to reload the page. The HTTP response is available in the handler. You just receive the response from the server, then put it where you like. In the answer, it is just `console.log(data)`. If you want to perform some other action with the data, please clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the work you put in, I think I understand better. I'm going to modify the PHP to match mine, and combine it with your console.log to append the data. 

I'll report back shortly. Your logic makes it more obvious.
Is there any benefit to having the PHP+HTML on one page, or no different?

Comment: @DNorthrup, ideally, PHP and HTML should be isolated. I'd recommend using a template engine such as Twig

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look into it. Would you mind reviewing the updated PHP script? I combined yours + mine and I think I'm super close. 
I purposely left your encode AND my decode because I'm confused about the order. 

The reason I ask is if I decode $response, I return 'null' and if I encode it it doesn't seem to return anything (No Console.log - Unsure what that means?)
If I decode $jsonobj (Which obv is just counter-active) It fails to parse.

Comment: @DNorthrup, if you just want to pass the JSON response to JavaScript, then you don't need to decode it - simply `echo $response;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126436/discussion-between-dnorthrup-and-ruslan-osmanov).