# Returned result from ajax won't print in console?

Tags: ajax, return-value, console.log

I am having trouble seeing the actual result of an ajax call. I doubt the issue is the server side because I checked my logs and my file returns "true" or "false" both strings. When this javascript runs, this prints to my console:

rentalValidation.js:64 result is status is success

rentalValidation.js:70 callback isstring

So ajax acknowledge that the ajax call was a success and the returned type is a string but it won't print the string.

Has this occurred to anyone before or does anyone have an idea why this is occurring? I also tried using dataType: "text", not much help.

```
Query.validator.addMethod("registeredStudent", 
  function(value, element) {

       $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "../model/rentIdCheckModel.php",
       data: {student_id : value},
       success: function (result, status) {
            console.log("result is " + result + "status is " + status);
       },
       error: function (xhr, errorText) {
           console.log('Error ' + errorText + xhr);
       }

      }).done(function(data) {
               console.log("callback is" + typeof (data) + data);
            });
       }, 
"Not a registered student. Try Again or create new student record.");
```

Comment: @user2864740 I reformatted my code. And my question is not how do I return the response from an ajax call. I already indicated that I am doing so using ajax's success feature AND the alternative callback feature .done. My question however was why I could log the typeof response I was getting but not the actual data? Can you help me answer that question?

Comment: It is likely an *empty string*. What does the *network tab* show for request data?

Comment: @user2864740 This is what is shows: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: @user2864740 I'm assuming the content-length confirms that it is returning an empty string. If so, how do reconcile that with the fact that my php file is returning true. The exact line in php looks like this 'return 'true';'. Should I change this?

Comment: That's correct, `Content-Length: 0` means "no data" which will manifest itself as an empty string - ya got a problem with the expectations of getting data back :} In PHP, `return` *terminates the current function* returning the value to the caller (or program, discarding the value). Unless the caller of said function *writes* the data response to the HTTP stream (ie. with `echo`) then it will be "lost"..

Comment: You are right, that fixed it! I would have never guessed that! I also learned about using the network tab to diagnose my problem. Thank you sir or ma'am. For other's references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Another note: It turns out Jquery Validator has a specific method to check the validity of an input via a back end call. It's called remote. http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/ One line of code > 10 lines