# Ajax with data doesn't work but it is success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "podpurne/genre_function.php",
    data: {
        pridej: pridej,
        identificator: identificator,
        genreS: genreS
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```

pridej, identificator and genreS has somethink inside.

podpurne/genre_function.php has code:

```
include"../pripojeni.php";
echo("<script>alert('ola');</script>");
if($_POST['pridej']){
    $db->query("INSERT INTO zanr_anime(identificator, zanr) VALUES 
    ('".$_POST['identificator']."','".$_POST['genreS']."'");
}
```

So if I call Ajax it give me success alert with OK. But nothing happened in genre_function.php, but if I type to URL genre_function.php give me alert with ola.

Any ideas why genre_function.php doesn't show me ola with ajax?

Comment: The echo part is just returned as a string but not executed. You get OK alert because you get ’something’ back from your php

Comment: Refer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call"

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) ([with explanation](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use serialize. Put ID in your form to call it.

```html
var data = $("#form-name").serialize();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
cache: false,
url: "podpurne/genre_function.php",
data: data,
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
});
```

Comment: You should add the advice to remove script tags from echo statement

Answer (score 1):

As you are doing AJAX request. Simply do `echo` from PHP file. And do `alert` in success function

**podpurne/genre_function.php**

```
include "../pripojeni.php";
echo('ola');
if($_POST['pridej']){
    $db->query("INSERT INTO zanr_anime(identificator, zanr) VALUES 
    ('".$_POST['identificator']."','".$_POST['genreS']."'");
}
```

**ajax code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "podpurne/genre_function.php",
    data: {
        pridej: pridej,
        identificator: identificator,
        genreS: genreS
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Also use **prepared statements** to get ride from SQL injections.