# why the ajax call runs and create duplicates

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have added an ajax button to send some data to a custom table in wordpress database.

Here is what i have there.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#holiday-submit").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //var name = jQuery("#dname").val();
        var date = jQuery("#holiday").val();
       var reason =jQuery("#holiday-reason").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "add_holiday", "holiday":date, "reason" :reason},
            success:function(data){
                jQuery("#holiday-status").addClass("success");
                jQuery("#holiday-status").html( "New Holiday added " + date +" " + reason);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Then in the function file, i have the following

```
function add_holiday(){
    $holiday = $_POST['holiday'];
    $reason = $_POST['reason'];
    global $wpdb;

    $table1= $wpdb->prefix.'holidays';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $table1 where holiday=$holiday");
        if($wpdb->num_rows == 0 ){
            $wpdb->insert(
                    $table1,
                array(
                    'holiday' => $holiday,
                    'reason'  => $reason
                ),
                array(
                    '%s'
                )
            );
            die();

            return true;
        }
        else{
            die();
            return false;
        }
    }

add_action('wp_ajax_add_holiday', 'add_holiday');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_holiday', 'add_holiday');
```

Both the ajax call and the relevant call back functions are working fine, and once the data is submitted using the following form, it sends to database and saves.

But, I do not want to have duplicate dates added to the database.

that is why I have added a condition to check whether the date already exists in the database table. Ideally, I need to show an error if the date already added to the database. nevertheless, the ajax call runs without considering the said condition.

what is the best way to address this.

this is my form and the output area .

```
<form action="" method="post">

            <input type="date" id="holiday" name="holiday">
            <input type="text" id="holiday-reason" placeholder="Holiday reason">
            <!--<input type="submit" id="holiday-submit">-->
            <input type="button" id="holiday-submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
<div id="holiday-status">

</div>

        <div id="current-holidays">
            <table id="declared-holidays" class="table table-success">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $table = $wpdb->prefix.'hr_holidays';

$result = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $table");

foreach ($result as $holiday_item){?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $holiday_item->holiday ;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $holiday_item->reason ;?></td>
</tr>
    <?php
}
?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Try returning the response of the select query  see what it contains

Comment: You probably need to use: where holiday='$holiday'

Comment: @Gerard is correct, but that would still leave your code vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @Gerard I already tried, but, still the ajax shows the success message. i mean, it still shows the message the added successfully message. what should i do to show an error instead ? would appriciate for a help

Comment: `var_dump($results)` then hit f12 in your browser, look at the network tab and see what problem is displayed in the ajax request

Comment: @andrew what are the areas which i needs to look at in this code, to prevent the sql injection vulnerabilities? some points would be appreciated for me to look into, and rectify them.

Comment: @andrew you mean, after the `return true` line correct ? i did that, there is no error showing in the network tab, or in the console.- but, now the data is not saving to database. I need to show an error since the data is not saving to db as it already exists.

Comment: nothing will show after a return statement as php will have already returned from the function; however, in your case, the return statement will never be reached because `die();` halts execution of the script

Comment: @andrew even I commented out `die();` still I don't get an error.  where have I messed up ? any clue..

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To debug your sql query use the network tab in your browser developer console and filter by xhr as shown in the image above

To deal with your sql injection vulnerability use prepared statements

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare("select * from $table1 where holiday=%s",$holiday)
);
var_dump($results); // this will show in the xhr request as shown above
```

Also watch out for xss vulnerabilities, never trust user input!

```
<td><?php echo esc_html($holiday_item->holiday) ;?></td>
<td><?php echo esc_html($holiday_item->reason) ;?></td>
```

Comment: i did the changes as above, but still i dont see any error in the network tab. still the code gives the success function as in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, it doesn't appear you're sending anything back to the data argument in the ajax success function.

Try echoing something from your function file:

```
  ....
  echo 'success';
  return true;
} else {
  die();
  echo 'duplicate';
  return false;
}
```

Than use a condition statement in the success function:

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data === 'success') {
    jQuery("#holiday-status").addClass("success");
    jQuery("#holiday-status").html( "New Holiday added " + date +" " + reason);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are right, i did try to alert the data which is sent back , but it is empty. then added `echo 'success' ;` after commenting out the `die();`. with this , the data saves to the db, but no error or success notification displayed on page. any tips ?

Comment: Have you tried console logging the data to see what is being returned? If nothing else, sometimes the `always()` method helps with debugging. `$.ajax(...).always(function(data) { console.log(data); })`

Comment: i did it and it out puts an empty. here is the output code. `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>E:\wamp64\www\wp-content\plugins\pluginname\includes\functions.php:722:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>success0` any clue?

Comment: The data returned to `$.ajax() ` is anything echoed by php. Whether it's something you explicitly echoed or something php echoed, like a warning or error. I'm assuming that `success` at the end there is what you're sending back, so something earlier in your code is echoing the rest of that stuff. I'm struggling to find where this is documented, but it's mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410773/how-to-return-data-from-php-to-a-jquery-ajax-call